# pgsql dynamic insert query execution

Tags: postgresql

Facing issue while executing dynamic insert query in postgresql

query used in function.

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tblename_' ||  NEW.id|| ' VALUES ($1)' USING NEW.* ;
```

While executing the above line it throws this error

`ERROR:  query "SELECT NEW.*" returned 14 columns`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You do not need the keyword "VALUES", as you are not specifying few selected columns. You can directly use it something like this

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tblename_' ||  NEW.id|| ' SELECT ($1).*'
USING NEW;
```